# Ansible: Multiple IP address variable lineinfile

Tags: ansible

I have got 3 hosts, X, Y, Z.
On host Q I have a directory /root.
 I have a file called temp.txt.

In that file I'd like to add the IP addresses from X, Y and Z to the host on Q.

How would this be possible? 
I've been reading about [Magic Variables](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) however I haven't got it working with groups...

Thusfar I got:

```
test: {% for host in groups['node'] %}
         {{ hostvars[host]['ansible_all_ipv4_addresses']['ipv4']['address'] }}
      {% endfor %}
```

However this put's out an error when I run it to test...:

```
fatal: [10.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "failed": true, "message": "Syntax Error while loading YAML.\n\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'True': line 2, column 8, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\n(could not open file to display line)"}
```

Is there an example somewhere which I may use?
Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: uggg, don't use lineinfile like this! Put it in a template. The future you (or future maintainer) will be much happier.

Comment: @tedder42 that's exactly what I did, used the `copy` module and made a template for it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're approaching that the wrong way.  There's no reason to try to set a variable the way you're doing it right now.

The best option here is probably to handle this with an Ansible loop, like this:

```
---
- hosts: all
  # there are no tasks in this play; this is just to explicitly gather
  # facts on all the hosts in the inventory.

- hosts: hostQ
  tasks:
    - lineinfile:
        create: true
        line: "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_default_ipv4.address }}"
        dest: /root/temp.txt
      with_items:
        - hostX
        - hostY
        - hostZ
```

This will gather facts on all the hosts in your inventory (which populates things like the `ansible_default_ipv4` hostvar), and then loops over a list of hostnames to extract those addresses to a file named `/root/temp.txt` on host `Q`.

Comment: Ah that's perfect @larsks, just the wrong approach, and it's much simpler! Thanks a lot!!